# python regular expression to pick up first instance of " target = x"

Tags: python, regex

I have a line `"blabla somehing something target = 4, hjieei, target = 8, abcd ef"`, I want to have a python regular expression to give me the output of 4, which is the number after the 1st "target = ".

I have tried `re.search('.*target = ([0-9.]+)’, line)`, it always give me value of `8` (Not `4`).
I have tried below code, and it doss not work either.
Would you pls help.

```
line = "target = 4, hjieei, target = 8, abcd ef"
while line:
    target_1 = re.search('/[^target = ([0-9.]+)]*/)', line)
    if target_1 and target_1.groups():
        print("found: ", target_1.group(1))'
    break
```

Comment: Remove the `.*` in `'.*Batch size = ([0-9.]+)'`

Comment: thanks Wiktor. Before my post, I have tried re.search('Batch size = ([0-9.]+)’, line), it gives me value of 4 on my experimental env, (i.e. my local pycharm IDE, but in my real sever environment which several complex files are working together, nothing is return, so i'm looking for a more robust solution :)

Comment: If you need a *real* answer, post *real* requirements, some *real* sample text with expected output.

Comment: So it's not sure that the string begins with `Batch size` @AndrewYang ? Wiktor's suggestion and my answer below works for the requirements as per the answer,  you need to provide more example to clarify the requirements better

Comment: thanks Wiktor, now issue sovled.

Comment: What issue? You just had to remove `.*`? Note you should not use `re.match` with `.*?` at the start, it is less efficient that removing `.*` and using `re.search`. You are currently using `re.search`, keep on using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the `.*` is matching everything greedily and ends up giving you the last match found, which is `8`.

So you would want to change your regex to start matching from the beginning by making it non-greedy by using `.*?`, abd then it will return the first match for you.

```
import re
line = "blabla somehing something target = 4, hjieei, target = 8, abcd ef"

target_1 = re.match(r'.*?target = ([0-9.]+)', line)
print(target_1.group(1))
```

The output will be `4`

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
import re
data = "Batch size = 4, hjieei, Batch size = 8, abcd ef"
out = re.findall('\d', data)[0]
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Would not `re.findall('\d', data)[0]` find first *digit* rather than *number*?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is always `target = [number]` at start of your string then you might do:

```
import re
txt = "target = 4, hjieei, target = 8, abcd ef"
number = re.findall(r'^target = (\d+)',txt)[0]
print(number) #prints 4
```

Note raw string (`r` before `'`) usage so I can use single `\` without need of escaping it and `\d` which is equivalent to `[0-9]`

Comment: thanks a lot Daweo, this is nice, although it does not fits into my other part of code, in some other situations, it works.

Comment: @AndrewYang: now I noticed that you also allows dot (`.`) inside number, to take this into account first argument of my `findall` should be altered to `r'^Batch size = ([\d.]+)'`